# Profile2 page no longer displays

Tags: users

After months of displaying without a glitch, I can no longer see the profile2 page. The sub-tabs (*Accounts* and *Profile*) are visible but it is the account page that displays regardless of the tab that is selected. The field forms of the Profile2 page have become inaccessible and, therefore, can no longer be edited.

Creating other profile types displays the tabs but, below, it's still the fields of the account page that display. The url changes as the different tabs are selected however (such as *...user/1/edit* for the account page and *...user/1/edit/main* for the profile2 page.)

Any idea of what's going on?

Thanks. :)

Comment: checked permissions?

Comment: Permissions look ok. That was user #1 anyway.